# Mixing and Matching Components for Zurb Foundation 6 Sites & Apps

Tags: zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6, zurb-foundation-apps

Is it possible to mix and match components for Zurb Foundation 6 for Sites/Apps?  For example, can I use the the [Card component](http://foundation.zurb.com/apps/docs/#!/card) of Zurb Foundation 6 for Apps in a Foundation 6 for Sites installation?

If so, how is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its is `very much possible` and I've been using them in my works. Simply make sure to `include appropriate css and js` files.

For example :

```
<!--Scripts-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/foundation-apps.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/iconic.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/motion-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>

<!--Styles-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation-apps.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/motion-ui.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css"/>
```

You this for local development and if you want, you can `compress all files into one minified (.min) file` for production.